# Angular service with generics in interface

Tags: angular, typescript, service

I'm stuck on solving a specific implementation for angular services. For a defined type of services I would like them to implement a common interface.

What I want to achieve is an interface that defines a generic property name and a specific type.

```js
// BaseService.ts

export interface BaseService {
  [key: string]: Data;
}

export interface Data {
  id: number;
  sequenceNumber: number;
  payload: any;
}

export class SampleService implements BaseService {

  data: Data = {
    id: 1,
    sequenceNumber: 1,
    payload: ''
  }
  
  test = this.data
}
```

Comment: Here is the attachments: 

the interface declaration in BaseService.ts
export interface BaseService {
    [key: string]: Data;
}

export interface Data {
    id: number;
    sequenceNumber: number;
    payload: any;
}

and the Service implementing the interface
export class SampleService implements BaseService {

  data: Data = {
    id: 1,
    sequenceNumber: 1,
    payload: ''
  }

  test = this.data

  constructor() { }
}

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, abstract classes can't declare properties with dynamic keys.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly - you want to set up a contract where the Service will have to have a property of a specified name, containing data of specified interface. I think this could work, or at least point you into the right direction.

```
export type BaseService<TData, TKey extends string> = {
  [key in TKey]: TData;
}


// example 1
export interface Data {
  id: number;
  sequenceNumber: number;
  payload: any;
}

// requires Data named as 'data'
export class SampleService implements BaseService<Data, 'data'> {

  data: Data = {
    id: 1,
    sequenceNumber: 1,
    payload: ''
  }
  
  test = this.data
}


// example 2
interface ResponseData {
  id: number;
    sequenceNumber: number;
    payload: string;
}

// requires ResponseData named as 'response'
export class ResponseService implements BaseService<ResponseData, 'response'> {
  response = {
    id: 1,
    sequenceNumber: 1,
    payload: ''
  }

  test = this.response
}
```